# How to insert a row every 24 lines using VBA in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to programming and need help.

I have an excel sheet that will have 8760 rows (for every hour in a year), in order to distinguish between each new day, I need to insert an empty row every 24 lines. I know I have to use a for loop but not sure what VBA syntax to use and so on.

This is what I have so far, I just don't know where to put the "every 24 lines condition":

```
For i = 1 to i = 8760
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
Next
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Comment: @FreeMan I doubt the macro recorder would help with this one. It might show you how to insert an entire row, but the rest requires some programming knowledge.

Comment: Might not show how to loop, but it's an opportunity to A) show some initiative, and B) learn to use the macro recorder which is a good way to _start_ learning, even though it doesn't write the best quality code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over the range of cells and use [VBA's `mod` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264708.aspx) to check to see if you should be inserting a row. You may also want to read [Modulo operator on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

```
Public Sub InsertRowOnceEvery24Rows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'adjust this to get the sheet you need

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A50") 'adjust this to whatever range of cells you need

    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If i Mod 24 = 0 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked.
I really appreciate your help!
One day I hope I can get more fluent in programming.

Comment: Shouldn't you be inserting rows in a reverse loop ;)

Comment: That was my first thought too @SiddharthRout, but then I realized that the reference to the cells wouldn't be changed by inserting rows in between them. =)

Comment: I see what you mean :)